# EF 6.1 Database.SqlQuery projection into complex type (many-to-many relationship)

Tags: c#, sql, database, performance, entity-framework

Is it in Entity Framework 6.1 possible to use the *Database.SqlQuery* command to execute a query, containing a many-to-many relation, and map it back to a DTO (using an intermediate DTO - i know this cannot be done in one go)? And how performed would such an action be?

This example is an **extremely simplified version** of a problem I'm currently facing. I'm just interested of what can can (cannot) be done with *Database.SqlQuery*.

I know i can use navigational properties (use Linq) but I'm investigating performance on a far more complex query. This is just a very simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve.

**Database**

[image]

**DTO**

```
 public class EventDto{

      public int EventId {get;set;}
      public string Name {get;set;}
      public string Slug {get;set;}

      public List<ArtistDto> Headliners {get;set;}
 }

 public class ArtistDto{

      public int ArtistId {get;set;}
      public string Name {get;set;}
      public string Bio {get;set;}
 }
```

**Temp DTO**

```
public class EventWithHeadlinersDto{

      public int EventId {get;set;}
      public string Name {get;set;}
      public string Slug {get;set;}

      public int ArtistId {get;set;}
      public string Name {get;set;}
      public string Bio {get;set;}
 }
```

**Code**

```
 return Context.Database.SqlQuery<EventWithHeadlinersDto>(@"
                                SELECT * FROM [Events] E
                                LEFT JOIN [Headliners] H ON E.EventId = H.EventId
                                LEFT JOIN [Artists] A ON H.ArtistId = A.ArtistId
                                WHERE E.eventid = @eventId",
                               new SqlParameter("eventId", eventId))
                               .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Did you mean to include `FROM Events E` in your SQL query?

Comment: Why don't you read the Intellisense tip of the `SqlQuery` method - it contains a whole help topic.

Comment: Don't you have models with navigation properties? So much easier (and maintainable) than SqlQuery.

Comment: @SteveGreene - I know i can use navigational properties (and i do have them) but I'm investigating (and profiling performance) on a SqlQuery method.

Comment: @IvanStoev please explain? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: When you hover with mouse the `SqlQuery` method (the code you posted) inside VS editor, a big tooltip will appear.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes it does - but no help on projecting into complex entities. By default it is not possible but I'm pretty sure it can be done by using the intermittent DTO - just not exacly how ;(

Comment: Well, may be I don't understand the question. Are you asking how to convert `List<EventWithHeadlinersDto>` to `List<EventDto>` with `Headliners` property populated?

Comment: @IvanStoev - yes. So i have a single EventDto with a List<Artist> (headliners). With the single query to the database.

Comment: Well, that's relative simple. The `SqlQuery` **is** a single database query, but note it will return **multiple** `EventWithHeadlinersDto` records with some duplicate data (`Event` fields), so you need to replace `FirstOrDefaultAsync` with `ToListAsync` and then convert the result set to the desired `EventDto` class.

Comment: @IvanStoev what would you recommend? A groupby, or itterating through the result yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requires some coding (basically replicating the EF query materialization process), but doable.

First, the temp DTO should be modified to include all the required fields, taking into account the `left joins` (using `nullable` types where needed):

```
public class EventWithHeadlinersDto
{
    // Event Info
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public string EventSlug { get; set; }
    // Artist Info
    public int? ArtistId { get; set; }
    public string ArtistName { get; set; }
    public string ArtistBio { get; set; }
}
```

Then you should ensure the SQL `SELECT` includes all the necessary columns, using the aliases when necessary in order to match DTO property names:

```
var sql = @"
    SELECT
       E.EventId, E.Name EventName, E.Slug EventSlug,
       A.ArtistId, A.Name ArtistName, A.Bio ArtistBio
    FROM [Events] E
    LEFT JOIN [Headliners] H ON E.EventId = H.EventId
    LEFT JOIN [Artists] A ON H.ArtistId = A.ArtistId
    WHERE E.EventId = @eventId";
```

Then execute the sql query and get the result DTO set:

```
var dataSet = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Finally transform it to the desired format:

```
var eventMap = new Dictionary<int, EventDto>();
var artistMap = new Dictionary<int, ArtistDto>();
foreach (var entry in dataSet)
{
    EventDto @event;
    if (!eventMap.TryGetValue(entry.EventId, out @event))
    {
        @event = new EventDto
        {
            EventId = entry.EventId, 
            Name = entry.EventName,
            Slug = entry.EventSlug,
            Headliners = new List<ArtistDto>()
        };
        eventMap.Add(@event.EventId, @event);
    }
    if (entry.ArtistId != null)
    {
        ArtistDto artist;
        if (!artistMap.TryGetValue(entry.ArtistId.Value, out artist))
        {
            artist = new ArtistDto
            {
                ArtistId = entry.ArtistId.Value,
                Name = entry.ArtistName,
                Bio = entry.ArtistBio,
            };
            artistMap.Add(artist.ArtistId, artist);
        }
        @event.Headliners.Add(artist);
    }
}
var resultSet = eventMap.Values.ToList();
```

Of course in the sample case the result set will contain only 0 or 1 items, but the above is applicable regardless of the applied filtering.